# Loading a form from a package at runtime

Tags: delphi, dll, plugins, package, bpl

I am currently working on a few Plugin concepts and came across during my research on the use of dlls or BPls and I have now decided to use bpls.

I would like to know when I have to use UnloadPackage (Package modules); best views because immediately after loading brings me nothing because the shape then immediately disappears

Current program structure

```
Hostapplication(PackageLoader.exe)
                |_Plugin.bpl
                 |_TPluginForm
```

[image]

PackageLoader.exe

```
var
  PackageModule : hModule;
  createProc: Procedure;
begin
  // Package laden
  try
  PackageModule := LoadPackage('plugin.bpl');
  If PackageModule <> 0 then
  begin
    @createProc := GetProcAddress( PackageModule, 'CreatePluginForm' ); // Funktion aus den Exports aufrufen
    if Assigned(CreateProc) then
      CreateProc
    else
      ShowMessage('GetProcAddress failed');
  end;
  finally
    //UnloadPackage(PackageModule);
  end;
end;
```

[image]

plugin.bpl - uPlugin.pas

```
unit uPlugin;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TPluginForm = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  PluginForm: TPluginForm;
  Status: Boolean;

implementation


uses
  uRandomString;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TPluginForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  User, pwd, mail: String;
  ul, pl, ml: Integer;
begin
  Status := True;
  ul := StrToInt(Edit1.Text);
  pl := StrToInt(Edit2.Text);
 // ml := StrToInt(Edit3.Text);
  while Status do
  begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    User := RandomString(ul);
    pwd := RandomString(pl);
    //mail := RandomString(ml) + '@' + RandomString(5)+'.de';

    Memo1.Lines.Add(User+':'+pwd); //+':'+mail);
  end;
end;

procedure TPluginForm.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Status := False;
end;

function CreatePluginForm(ApplicationHandle, ParentHandle: THandle): boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  PluginForm := TPluginForm.Create(nil);
  try
    PluginForm.Show;
    //PluginForm.ShowModal;
  finally

  end;
end;


exports
  CreatePluginForm;

initialization
  RegisterClass(TPluginForm);

finalization
  UnRegisterClass(TPluginForm);

end.
```

Comment: Here is my upvote for a perfectly good question (I started to up-vote ALL decent questions that have a negative score and no explanation for why they have been downvoted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When to unload the package depends on the design of your application. Given that we don't know much about it, it is hard to give specific advice. One option is that you don't unload the package. Why do you feel that you need to do so? If there is a need to unload you must make sure that no code from the package is still running. You show a form from the package. That form must have been destroyed by the time you come to unload the package.

The big problem that I can see is in the way you import that function. It is declared like this in the package:

```
function CreatePluginForm(ApplicationHandle, ParentHandle: THandle): Boolean;
begin
  ....
end;

exports
  CreatePluginForm;
```

And then you import it like this:

```
var
  createProc: Procedure;
....
@createProc := GetProcAddress(PackageModule, 'CreatePluginForm');
if Assigned(CreateProc) then
  CreateProc
```

You need to declare `createProc` with a matching signature:

```
var
  createProc: function(ApplicationHandle, ParentHandle: THandle): Boolean;
```

And then when you call it you need to pass the two handles, and do something with the return value.

Your code also leaks `PluginForm`.

Finally, `THandle` would appear to be the wrong type. I think you meant to use `HWND`. Although I don't see why you don't pass VCL objects around. After all, you chose to use packages which means that you can pass the parent control directly. And you certainly don't need to pass anything related to the application because the plugin can already see the application.

Comment: Thanks for this advanced answer but i still don't know when i have to use unloadPackage because if i load the package to show my form my packageloading procedure ends and i got no acces to unload it later for example when my main apllication is closed or when the plugin form is closed.

Comment: I've added some more text. Fundamentally it's down to you and the decision will depend on your app design. You cannot unload the package until you've finished using it. As for having access to the package module, you have to remember that until you unload it.